# Why do I need to use [ ] (square brackets) when moving data from register to memory, but not when other way around?

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, nasm

This is the code I have and it works fine:

```
section .bss
    bufflen equ 1024
    buff: resb bufflen

    whatread: resb 4

section .data

section .text

global main

main:
    nop
    read:
        mov eax,3           ; Specify sys_read
        mov ebx,0           ; Specify standard input
        mov ecx,buff        ; Where to read to...
        mov edx,bufflen     ; How long to read
        int 80h             ; Tell linux to do its magic

                            ; Eax currently has the return value from linux system call..
        add eax, 30h        ; Convert number to ASCII digit
        mov [whatread],eax  ; Store how many bytes has been read to memory at loc **whatread**

        mov eax,4           ; Specify sys_write
        mov ebx,1           ; Specify standart output
        mov ecx,whatread    ; Get the address of whatread to ecx
        mov edx,4           ; number of bytes to be written
        int 80h             ; Tell linux to do its work

        mov eax, 1; 
        mov ebx, 0; 
        int 80h
```

Here is a simple run and output:

```
koray@koray-VirtualBox:~/asm/buffasm$ nasm -f elf -g -F dwarf buff.asm
koray@koray-VirtualBox:~/asm/buffasm$ gcc -o buff buff.o
koray@koray-VirtualBox:~/asm/buffasm$ ./buff
p
2koray@koray-VirtualBox:~/asm/buffasm$ ./buff
ppp
4koray@koray-VirtualBox:~/asm/buffasm$
```

My question is: What is with these 2 instructions:

```
        mov [whatread],eax  ; Store how many byte reads info to memory at loc whatread
        mov ecx,whatread    ; Get the address of whatread in ecx
```

Why the first one works with [] but the other one without?

When I try replacing the second line above with:

```
        mov ecx,[whatread]  ; Get the address of whatread in ecx
```

the executable will not run properly, it will not shown anything in the console.

Comment: `mov ecx, whatread` as your comment says loads the address not the value. `mov ecx, [whatread]` also works and loads the value. As such, you need to use `[]` when accessing memory in both directions. `mov ecx, whatread` does not access memory, it's loading an address stored as an immediate. It's the `mov r/m32, imm32` instruction.

Comment: @Jester Can you pleasee see my edit? It does not work when I try ecx,[whatread]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using brackets and not using brackets are basically two different things:

A bracket means that the value in the memory at the given address is meant.

An expression without a bracket means that the address (or value) itself is meant.

Examples:

```
mov ecx, 1234
```

Means: Write the value 1234 to the register ecx

```
mov ecx, [1234]
```

Means: Write the value that is stored in memory at address 1234 to the register ecx

```
mov [1234], ecx
```

Means: Write the value stored in ecx to the memory at address 1234

```
mov 1234, ecx
```

... makes no sense (in this syntax) because 1234 is a constant number which cannot be changed.

Linux "write" syscall (INT 80h, EAX=4) requires the address of the value to be written, not the value itself!

This is why you do not use brackets at this position!

Comment: Does this mean Linux expects me to pass the memory address of the value I want to use in eax when I am making a call, but returns the value itself in the registry eax?

Comment: You can use the "man 2 write" command in the shell to find out about what arguments WRITE expects and what return value you get. Linux expects a memory address in ECX, which points to the stuff you want to print. After the interrupt int 80h, you will get the return value of WRITE in eax, which is the amount of bytes it printed out (and not what it printed out).

Comment: I think it is a bad cosmetic style for to access a memory location without to use brackets in the source. Example for MASM: "VALUE DW 0" + "mov VALUE, cx" or "mov cx, VALUE", "VALUE DB 0" + "mov VALUE, cl" or "mov cl, VALUE". These instruction can be used with or without brackets using MASM for to access the memory location of VALUE. But for to prevent a missunderstanding und confusing if the used name is a constant, or a memory location it is more clear with using brackets.